# I burn what you can’t protect

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> My prefix is not acquitted
>   My infix demands respect
>   My suffix is a price
>   I burn what you can’t protect

What word am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word could be:

> **Conflagrate**.

```
My prefix is not acquitted
```

> If someone is not acquitted, they are considered by the state to be a convict, or a **Con**.

```
My infix demands respect
```

> A **Flag** is to be respected.

```
My suffix is a price
```

> A **Rate** is a synonym for price.

```
I burn what you can’t protect
```

> Hence, **Conflagrate**, a synonym for catching fire.

Thanks to @DavidLewis for pointing out a flaw in my answer!

Comment: Seems like rot13(pbasyntengr) would fit better =)

Comment: @DavidLewis Absolutely! I'll change my response, thank you!